# How to import fontawesome to Roots Theme? (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress

I've locally compiled the `fontawesome.less` to my `main.min.css`, and also changed the font path in `variables.less`, but I still having problem with loading the icons? Can't figure out why. I've successfully loaded it through this way on my local html file but can't get through on WordPress. BTW, I'm using WinLess as my LESS compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that your final minified CSS is linking to the fonts. It sounds like you're missing the path to the fonts – check your inspector tool.

Another alternative is to load from a CDN, e.g.

```
/**
 * Enqueue javascript
 *
 */
if( !function_exists( "theme_js" ) ) {

    function theme_js(){

        wp_register_script( 'fontawesome', 'https://use.fontawesome.com/9a8a083038.js',
            array('jquery'),
            '4.7.1', true);


        wp_enqueue_script( 'fontawesome' );

    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'datonomy_theme_js' );
```

Comment: Though I just went to BootstrapCDN and linked fontawesome css to solve the problem, I think you are right, I didn't add my script correctly.